# Expression "making a bid/break for freedom"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What is the difference between "making a bid for freedom" and "making a break for freedom"? In which situations would one use one and not the other?

Answer (score 1):

In the context you're referencing, a **bid** is

> an attempt or effort to achieve something

whereas a **break** is

> • a rush or dash in a particular direction, esp. by an attacking player or team : *he made a bounce pass for a basket on the break in the second quarter*.
>   • a breakout, esp. from prison.

The distinction is that a *bid* may or may not risk anything, whereas a *break* often risks much or all.

[References from NOAD]

Comment: Hmm - it's worth noting that a bid is very literally when you propose a price to be paid for something, whether a bet like stock options, or for purchase at an auction. (I think any attempt at freedom carries a price, a risk, you're putting something on the line - psychologically or otherwise!)  A "break for..." is indeed when you break out of some situation, physical or metaphorical. I had to break for freedom from my aged mother; on the other metaphor anytime you take a business risk to achieve more independence, that's a bid for freedom (it's pricey, and risky too).

Comment: In a bid for freedom, you are putting up some of your own wealth/time/etc in a bid for freedom. The "bid" is how much you're putting on the line.  (Eg: **"Well I've quit my job, and put $50,000 on the line in my bid for freedom in a new life running a coffee shop."**) Whereas in a break for freedom, you're about to destroy a prison, marriage, or other physical or social institution so that you can be free.  (Indeed you may be eg. shot attempting to escape in the process.)